# vim: trying to use autocompletion for FuzzyFinder

Tags: vim

I have installed FuzzyFinder but the autocompletion is not working for me..

I'm writing `:FufFile pattern:<enter>` then I start to write the name of a file inside of the project but it doesn't show anything.. It just says: `Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found`.

I run `FufRenewCache:` before

I installed FF using VAM.

Any idea?

Javi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FuzzyFinder doesn't search recursively through a project. You have to enter a few characters of a directory and hit enter down the path to the file. If you're looking for a program that does a recursive search through the entire project you might look into [command-T](https://github.com/wincent/Command-T).

If this isn't what you were looking for it would help to know what pattern you're typing in and what file path you're trying to access.

Comment: thanks, I have installed FuzzyFinder in another computer so I know how it works..I write `:FufFile pattern:<enter>` and then at the top I start to write after `File>pattern:` the name of file or a folder, and then a pop up shows the files that matches the letters I'm writing..but that doesn't happen in my current pc..

Comment: @tirengarfio what pattern, specifically, are you typing in?

Comment: @tirengarfio I ask because the likelihood is that the pattern you're typing is not matching the files in the current directory. Type `:FufFile *<Enter>` and see if anything comes up.

Comment: Also be sure to `:pwd`, just to ensure that you're working in the directory you think you are.  (If I had a dollar for every time something misbehaved in an inexplicable way just because I was in the wrong directory...)

Comment: what I was missing was including this lines in .vimrc: `let g:fuf_abbrevMap = {
    \   "^pattern:" : [
    \     "*",
    \     "app/*",
    \     "app/config/**/",
    \     "src/**/",
    \   ],
    \ }.` Now it works autocompleting the name of the file that inside that folders.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search recursively through directories, try to prepend `**/` to your pattern.